# Electron packager not set icon

Tags: electron

I have `"electron-packager": "^8.2.0"`  in my package.json
and I tried to make a package of `electron` app with these command:

```
electron-packager ./ app --win --icon=https://www.google.it/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico
```

and

```
electron-packager ./ app --win --icon="https://www.google.it/images/branding/product/ico/googleg_lodp.ico"
```

but the icon is not setted and it set default atom icon.

I have tried also with local file, but the icon is still default.

Comment: now it working...with file local...same command..i believe the problem was icon file but why is a mistery..is not dimension because a second image with same dimensions work.... :/ electron-packager ./ app --win --icon="C:\xampp\htdocs\app\assets\images\icon.ico" --overwrite –